# SiteMapPath - passing params through routing and querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I am using MVCSiteMapProvider 4.6.7 in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I have this in the `mvc.sitemap` file:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="UserManager" controller="User" action="Index">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="UserAdd" controller="User" action="Create"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="UserEdit" controller="User" action="Edit" 
                       preservedRouteParameters="id"
                      key="User_Edit"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="UserView" controller="User" action="Details"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I am showing a Site Map Path like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumbNav">
   @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
</div>
```

When I navigate to `http://siteurl/User/Edit/2`, the site map path is displayed, but when I navigate to `http://siteurl/User/Edit?id=2`, it is not.

Removing `preservedRouteParameters="id"` will reverse the situation ( site map displayed with `.../Edit?id=2`, but not with `.../Edit/2`)

Is there a way to make them both work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a bug, which has now been fixed in [v4.6.10](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases/tag/v4.6.10) (thanks for the report).

The problem is that "id" is specified as an optional route value, in which case MVC automatically generates a route value with "id/null" when "id" is not provided as a route value in the URL. Since route values take precedence over query string values when finding the "current" node, the route value was not being overwritten in this case. An exception was added for this specific case in v4.6.10 to overwrite route values that are empty so the match will be done with the query string value instead of the empty route value.

After you upgrade, using `preservedRouteParameters="id"` will match in both cases, and the breadcrumb will be shown.

Comment: The problem was fixed after upgrading to 4.6.10. Thank you!